# How to view System preferences in BrowserStack?

Tags: testing, system, browserstack

I am using BrowserStack for cross platform/cross browser testing of web application, and I need to test it using different system configurations. Can you, kindly advise, if I am able to view/change System Prefenerces in BrowserStack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, BrowserStack does not allows changing the System Preferences of the remote machine.